# Word2vec build vocab adds TM to words

Tags: word2vec

I'm trying to make convert my textdata to vectors. I would like to transform the word ultraram to a vector. I added the word to the model using model.build_vocab, but only ultraramTM is added. What did i do wrong

```
        model.save("word2vec.model2")
        model = Word2Vec.load("word2vec.model2")
        model.build_vocab(data_tokenized, update=True)
        # Store just the words + their trained embeddings.
        word_vectors = model.wv
        word_vectors.save("word2vec.wordvectors2")
        # Load back with memory-mapping = read-only, shared across processes.
        self.wv = KeyedVectors.load("word2vec.wordvectors2", mmap='r')
        
for i in self.wv.key_to_index:
            if "ultrar" in i:
                print(i)
```

ultraram™
manufactureultraram™
ultrarobust
ultrarare
ultrarealistic
ultrarelativistic

it shows some words with a TM. What does this mean? and how can i add the word "utraram" without the tm.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a `™` at the end of some tokens, then those tokens, with the `™`, were exactly what had been passed into the model when its vocabulary was first established.

If you don't want them, you'd have to strip them during your tokenization. (You current question/code doesn't show how you might have tokenized your data.)

Separately:

Directly using `.load()` to replace a `Word2Vec` model's existing `KeyedVectors` won't in general be reliable: a `Word2Vec` isn't expecting that to change separate from its own initialization/training.

It may work in this limited case – eloading exactly the same word-vectors as were just saved – but in such a case, it's unclear why you'd want to do it. From the comment it seems the motivation here might be to save some memory. However, if you're only looking-up word-vectors, you don't the full `Word2Vec` model at all. You can just use the set-of-`KeyedVectors` alone (for more memory savings).